# Keeping production credentials / secrets safe on Microsoft Azure and Team Foundation Server

Tags: azure, tfs, credentials, secret-key

We are using TFS for our Microsoft Azure application. In that application, we have  Production, Staging and Local environments. Until now I was the only developer in the project, so we didn't have any problem with the security of credentials in development environment.

Our target is to keep production credentials safe and out of the reach of other developers. What is the best practice to do this on Microsoft Azure and Team Foundation Server Online?

Thanks.

Edit:

I'm keeping that secrets in "ServiceConfiguration" files of Azure:
[image]

Is it possible to keep ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg file exclusively available to a few person or a group in TFS? Maybe that can fix the issue. Because all secrets of Production env. are in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep production passwords in Azure portal:
[image: Azure Web-Site configuration page]

These override your `web.config` settings, similar to `web.config` transformations. You can override  `app.settings` and connection strings.

This way you don't have to keep production credentials in your version control system, and only people with access to azure portal will be able to see these credentials.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how I do it, but what I was wondering is, how to exclude these configuration files like ServiceConfiguration.Production from source control and other developers. I added an image as a detail to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Ah! these are Web-Roles. I'm talking about Web-Sites. With web-roles I'm not sure how this can be worked about. I'd try to remove sensitive settings from `.cscfg` files and keep these settings in Azure. But there is a chance that on deployment all settings will be overwritten by new `.cscfg` file. Try this on non-prod instance, it might work.

Comment: Yeah, it'll be overwritten and I think it functions in the same way with websites. My idea is to keep this configuration files exclusively available to a few person, but I don't know if it is possible in TFS. I'll give a bit details to my question. Thank you!

Comment: In Web-Sites there is no `.cscfg` file. So whatever you have set in portal, it'll stay like that with deployment. Unless you modify settings via PowerShell commands. I see what you are trying to achieve, but not sure if TFS can give you that. I can imagine a way to do it, but don't know your deployment pipeline... and my ways involve a lot of kludging. Let's wait for other answers -)